# JQL for "Issues added to sprint after start time"

Tags: jira, jql

In the sprint report jira reports that any issue with a * on it has been added after the sprint started. How can i get the JQL for that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it uses JQL there. If you use Chrome, Inspect Element and the network tab you'll probably see which REST resource for JIRA Agile is called to get that data

Comment: It is JQL, data sent in the header is "jql=issueFunction+in+addedAfterSprintStart(..)"
I think they don't have a field for it so it's calculated based on sprint start and creation date.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a way with this add-on

https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-Agile

Answer (score -1):

If you have `ScriptRunner` installed, you can use `issueFunction` in `addedAfterSprintStart(board name, sprint name)` .

Comment: ScriptRunner's docs say that function is "not available". See near the bottom of this page: http://scriptrunner-docs.connect.adaptavist.com/jiracloud/jql-aliases.html